# Add icon in button? help me please

Tags: html, css

My code noob :(

I want to add 1 icon in each button, if you have to change any class, no problem. I am learning HTML CSS and here I got lost. Thank you!

example: https://i.gyazo.com/f6ed36f084b7b39c153c6b63af850691.png

```css
.social-sharing {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.social-sharing ul.menu-social {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrapwrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}


.social-sharing ul.menu-social li.telefono {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  
}

.social-sharing ul.menu-social li.next {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #3d3d;
}

.social-sharing ul.menu-social li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<aside class="social-sharing">
    <ul class="menu-social">
    
    <li class="social-item telefono"><a href="#">Teléfono</a></li>
      <li class="social-item telefono"><a href="#">Whatsapp</a></li>
        
    
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add svg image in link (good solution)

```
<li class="social-item telefono"><a href="#">
<svg width="10" height="20" viewBox="0 0 10 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d=" YOUR PATH "></path></svg>
Whatsapp</a></li>
```

or add extra padding for icon and use background-image (bad solution)

```
a {padding-left: 80px; padding-right: 40px; background-image: url(....); background-position: 40px center; background-size: 40px 40px; background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat}
```

or add pseudoelement and put image in it

```
a {position: relative; padding-left: 80px; padding-right: 40px;}
a:before {position: absolute; left: 40px; top: 20px; width: 40px; height: 40px; background: url(......) 50% 50% no-repeat; background-size: contain;}
```